# Korean Syllable PHP or JavaScript Romanizer (or any other alternative?)

Tags: javascript, php

I'd like to make a transliterator from the Korean alphabet (hangul) to the Latin alphabet (romanization) but it seems that (after having been trying many times without success) the use of a simple associated array isn't the proper thing to do.

Here is the method I have been trying to work hard on so far:

https://gist.github.com/1154969

I tried replacing the Hiragana by Korean syllables but I couldn't get it working.

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Can you please elaborate why your first attempts werent successful?

Comment: It only worked in one way : from the Latin alphabet to Korean (when I try in the other way it doesn't work)

Answer (score 0):

Romanizing a text is easy, but the other way around is quite difficult. For instance in Japanese (which I know better than Korean), なん is written as "nan", the first syllable being "na" and the second being "n". Your code would have to distinguish between the two syllables in some way, because if it would turn the first n into a ん instead of the second, your parser would be left with "an", which is a non-existent syllable in Japanese.

The way to approach this **would** in its most basic form involve an associative array. Instead of mass-replacing the keys with their values in one go, you'd have to look for the longest possible syllables first and replace those in one go. So first, you'd go for syllables like "shi", the for syllables like "na" and lastly for syllables like "n". If you do it that way, all Asian languages I know of should be safely converted back into their own alphabet, though keep in mind that this may still cause problems if different syllables have the same Romanized form of writing.

Comment: I don't think it will be that easy. `an` might be non-existent, but `a` `n` certainly is not, thus it would be correct to transcribe `nan` to `んあん` (even if it makes no sense). Also Hepburn is not the only romanization system for japanese.

Comment: I only wanna transliterate from Korean to Latin. The official Korean transcription only has one way of writing for each  syllable, so that should be in theory a long but a very easy operation : 가=ga; 강=gang; etc.

Comment: I don't exactly see how it would be long? The "long" bit would be setting up the arrays in the right order, but everything else could be a loop with several replaces.

@Yoshi That problem is "solved" by replacing longer syllables first. It only messes up if んあん or something similar would actually be a naturally occurring sequence, though I don't think it is, in Japanese at least. I can't think of a naturally occurring Japanese sequence of syllables that is made ambiguous after romanizing it. From what I gather, in Korean it isn't a problem either.

Comment: I tried only replacing some hiragana characters by Korean syllables (in the "from hiragana" part in the "kana.php" file on https://gist.github.com/1154969) and then made the "from hiragana" operation on the "index.php" page, though I could not get the romanization, I was given only what I had written in the bar in Korean.    Seems like it's a problem related to Korean language itself within PHP operations.

Comment: @JeroenvandenBroek If not using modified hepburn `簡易`, for example, could be ambiguous after romanization. Though this is off-topic, and I should not press this discussion any longer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Since you simply want to expand some specific symbols (hangul syllables) in original string to other pre-defined sequences (romanization), use combination of object lookup where you'd store hangul as key and romanization as value and `String.replace`'s ability to generate replacements through function.

I'll use katakana as part of example because I too know Japanese better :) but you only need to fill replacement table with correct hangul for it to work:

```
var hangul_syllable_to_roman = {
    '가' : 'ga',
    '강' : 'gang',
    'カ' : 'ka',
    'タ' : 'ta',
    'ナ' : 'na'
}

function one_hangul_syllable_to_roman(syllable) {
    var roman = hangul_syllable_to_roman[syllable]
    // if we have suitable replacement - do it, if not - just return original back
    if (roman) { return roman } else { return syllable }
}

function hangul_to_roman(hangul) {
    return hangul.replace(/./gm, one_hangul_syllable_to_roman)
}

document.write(hangul_to_roman('가강 カタカナ some other text'))
// gagang katakana some other text
```

Comment: Could you tell me how to test your code? I'm sadly only an amateur (for the moment!) in programing PHP. Thank you!

Comment: That's pure JS - you can do entire transliteration without need for server-side processing at all. Run it in browser's console, save it to .js and embed to any HTML or see it in action on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LGRAq/

Comment: Sorry for my Javascript skills.. I'm not sure how to use jsfiddle or how to get your script working on my website. Originally, I just wanted to get something like https://gist.github.com/1154969 . It only needs a click and the characters are replaced.

Comment: I have feeling you won't go too far with just copy/pasting, so you'd need to either get basic understanding yourself or hire somebody. This piece of code can be saved to .js file and loaded with `<script>` in HTML as usual. Attaching it to some button or other widget is out of scope for this particular question.